# How to load a webpage to refresh data using Cron Job in Cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a webpage in Php domain.com/page/ and I need that page to load automatically every month to refresh the data because I am pulling data on that page from another app. Can you help me on the Cron command to load that webpage?

Comment: depends on your version of cPanel, but your command will be `php path/to/your/php/script.php` and then you'll set the day to 1 so that it runs on the first of each month

Comment: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a more appropriate place to ask this. Also there are many tutorials for adding cron jobs through cpanel at the end of a Google search.

Comment: @iam-decoder I have a 11.48.4 (build 4) version of cpanel, I tried a lot of commands but seems to not work. I tried curl http://domain.com/folder/folder/index.php >/dev/null 2>&1 it doesn't work and I don't know how I could test this.

Comment: @GOPalmer Thanks for your comment, I tried googling first they seem to be technical and I don't really understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your shell and type crontab -e

add this line to the contab

0 0 1 * * wget http://domain.com/page/  >/dev/null

Comment: What does 0 0 1 * * mean?

Comment: This means every first day of the month.

Comment: its in this order Minute - Hour - Day - Month - Day of the week .

Comment: I didnt saw you are using cpanel, in cpanel you can use the wizard and simply add this line in the command field "wget http://domain.com/page/ >/dev/null"

Comment: you can set it to once a minute * * * * * wget http://domain.com/page  and 2>&1 | mail -s "dump" example@mail.example and see what uou get in your mail

Comment: Make sure you change it back because it will run every minute